# Problems serializing struct with nlohmann's json library

Tags: c++, json, serialization, struct, nlohmann-json

I am trying to serialize this struct with nlohmann's json library (the struct is defined in the file JsonResponsePacketSerializer.h):

```
typedef struct GetRoomsResponse
{
    unsigned int status;
    std::vector<RoomData> rooms;
}GetRoomsResponse;
```

where RoomData is another struct defined in the file Room.h:

```
typedef struct RoomData
{
    unsigned int id;
    std::string name;
    unsigned int maxPlayers;
    unsigned int numOfQuestionsInGame;
    unsigned int timePerQuestion;
    unsigned int isActive;
}RoomData;
```

To serialize this struct, I defined this user-macro as per nlohmann's documentation:

```
NLOHMANN_DEFINE_TYPE_NON_INTRUSIVE(GetRoomsResponse, status, rooms);
```

But this results in many errors I'm assuming because it doesn't know how to serialize the struct RoomData that is inside the struct GetRoomsResponse.

I tried adding a default constructor to RoomData (even though I'm pretty sure structs have a default constructor by default) and it didn't work.

Comment: you need to add `NLOHMANN_DEFINE_TYPE_NON_INTRUSIVE` (or `to_json` and `from_json`) for `RoomData`

Comment: `typedef struct ClassName {...} ClassName;` is a C habit that imho shouldn't be used when writing C++ code; simply use `struct ClassName { ... };` instead for the same effect. (Neither `GetRoomsResponse` nor `RoomData` are type definitions that can be used in C anyways.)

Comment: @fabian Thanks! I was confused about people not using typedef but still not having to type struct when using the struct, but that's just because I was used to C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by @AlanBirties, all components of a struct must be serializable for the struct itself to be serializable ([documentaiton](https://github.com/nlohmann/json#arbitrary-types-conversions)).

Here is some sample code which also declares the structures in the standard `C++` style.

### Sample Code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "nlohmann/json.hpp"

struct RoomData {
    unsigned int id;
    std::string name;
    unsigned int maxPlayers;
    unsigned int numOfQuestionsInGame;
    unsigned int timePerQuestion;
    unsigned int isActive;
};

struct GetRoomsResponse {
    unsigned int status;
    std::vector<RoomData> rooms;
};

NLOHMANN_DEFINE_TYPE_NON_INTRUSIVE(RoomData, id, name, maxPlayers, numOfQuestionsInGame, timePerQue\
stion, isActive);
NLOHMANN_DEFINE_TYPE_NON_INTRUSIVE(GetRoomsResponse, status, rooms);

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

    RoomData r0{1, "abc", 2, 3, 4, 5}, r1{6, "def", 7, 8, 9, 10};
    GetRoomsResponse resp{0, {r0, r1}};

    nlohmann::json j{resp};
    cout << j << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
[{"rooms":[{"id":1,"isActive":5,"maxPlayers":2,"name":"abc","numOfQuestionsInGame":3,"timePerQue\
stion":4},{"id":6,"isActive":10,"maxPlayers":7,"name":"def","numOfQuestionsInGame":8,"timePerQue\
stion":9}],"status":0}]
```